# Convert SLIM to HAML or ERB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

Is there any way to convert [SLIM](http://slim-lang.com/) file to [HAML](http://haml.info/) or ERB? I googled for any existing web sites (like html2haml.heroku.com/, or css2sass.heroku.com) which can do this convert, but still no luck. Thanks.

SLIM:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any, but Texmate allows you to convert slim to html ([link](https://gist.github.com/865475))

Maybe you can use that and than html2haml ?

Hope this still saves you a bit of time.

Comment: This is not a solution to convert slim to haml.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at what the [Slim documentation](http://rdoc.info/gems/slim/frames) has to say:

**Slim can be converted to ERB using slimrb or `Slim::ERBConverter` which are both included in the Slim gem**

- Haml2Slim converter
- ERB2Slim, HTML2Slim converter

It should be noted that the ERB conversion is rather sloppy. In fact I'm working on a Slim fork to improve the output when converting Slim templates to ERB, but it's [not quite ready yet](https://github.com/SteveBenner/slim).